# Mobile Redirection: Meta or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, meta-tags, redirect

**What type of client-side redirection on mobile devices is the most reliable?**

This is more of a fundamental question. Lets only assume that we need to deal with iOS and Android devices at the moment (no BB or Windows) and the webpage that has the redirect is only a pass-through page (meaning that it does it's job, then has to pass the user to the next page)

I found [this blog post](http://joshmccarty.com/2011/08/redirect-in-sharepoint-using-meta-vs-javascript/), which talks about the pros/cons of each of them.

I feel the biggest con of the meta redirect is the fact that it makes an entry in the browser history.

The JavaScript redirect in my opinion seems less reliable, but has a better UX (no browser history entry, and the fact that you can put some logic and dynamic values in it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a mix of both approaches: create a javascript redirect with 300 ms or so of delay. As backup (in case javascript is disabled or just doesn't work for any reason), put on your page a meta redirect with 300 ms more than the javascript redirect.

Comment: Great idea... I really wish the meta redirect page didn't get placed inside the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

I find that this little plugin is great for mobile detection - http://detectmobilebrowsers.com. I use the jQuery version on that page, but there are also other scripts for PHP, ASP, pure javascript etc.

So with the jQuery version you'd just do this for a redirect -

```
if($.browser.mobile) {

   window.location = 'http://yourmobilesite.com'; 

}
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm not looking on how to do the redirection when mobile is found, just the best way to perform a redirect on a mobile device.